# Number Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

These are the terms the question gave me.
Term 1 = 1 
Term 2 = 1
Term 3 = 2
Term 4 = 3
Term 5 = 5 
Term 6 = 8 
Term 7 = 13
Term n = ?

I found out the pattern which is Term 2 is Term 1 + 0. Term 3 is Term 2 +Term 1 and Term 4 is Term 3 + Term 2. But what is the equation for finding term "n"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: This is called the Fibonacci sequence, the formula for the nth term can be found on Wikipedia,

Answer (score 3):

The *explicit* formula (which is a formula in which you just need to plug in $n$ and you'll get the answer) for the $n$-th Fibonacci number is $$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \cdot \left[ \left( \frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n - \left( \frac{1- \sqrt 5}{2} \right)^n \right]$$ whereas the *recursive* formula (which is a formula of the sequence in terms of other terms of the sequence) is simply what you said $$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$$ Notice that to find the nth term using the recursive formula you need all the terms before it, but the explicit formula does not require that.

The explicit formula is connected to the *golden ratio* which you might have heard of. See [this](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is called Fibonacci sequence.

It's first term is 0 and second term is 1.

n+1 th term is given by...

$T_{n+1}=T_n+T_{n-1}$

Where n=1, 2, 3,.....

Hope this helped.